# Video processing with GPUImage Android

Tags: android, gpuimage

I want to use [GPUImage Android](https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage) to process video in real time. I see example that creating pictures with different filters but I didnt find any example of recording video with filters. Is this possible with GPUImage Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

android-gpuimage library does not support video recording but you can try using the android-gpuimage-videorecording library. It is a fork of the gpu-image for android that provides also the video recording functionality

[android-gpuimage-videorecording](https://github.com/westbrett/android-gpuimage-videorecording)

see the GPUImageMovieWriter class

It should point you in the right direction for developing your own video writer on top of GPUImage.

The idea is to:

- draw on current screen surface
- switch to encoder input surface and draw previous frame buffer again on it
- switch back to screen surface

other useful links:
    [EGL surface helper](https://github.com/google/grafika),
    [Media encoder](https://github.com/saki4510t/AudioVideoRecordingSample)

Comment: just added more info, obviously I cannot write all code here. It should be enough for pointing people that need to handling this kind of issue in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

[GPUVideo-android](https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/GPUVideo-android)

This library apply video filter on generate an Mp4 and on ExoPlayer video and Video Recording with Camera2.
Android MediaCodec API is used this library.

This library has many types of filters.
[Filters link](https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/GPUVideo-android/tree/master/gpuv/src/main/java/com/daasuu/gpuv/egl/filter)